# Using psfrag with LaTeX counters (insert counter number directly in eps figure)?

Tags: counters, eps, psfrag

I am writing an organic chemistry dissertation using (pdf)LaTeX. The content of the thesis contains a large amount of numbered chemical structures. The chemical structure drawings were generated using ChemDraw and exported to eps format. Since there are literally hundreds of numbered structures, I wrote a macro that uses a custom counter to keep track of the numbers:

```
\newcounter{compound}
\def\thecompound{\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{compound}}}
\newcommand{\cmp}[1]{\refstepcounter{compound}\label{cmp:#1}\textsf{\scriptsize{\thecompound}}}
```

Each time I want to number a compound, I simply write the command (which automatically increments the counter):

```
\cmp{uniquestring}
```

The problem I am having is finding an efficient way to put the compound numbers on the structural drawings (eps figures). What I am using right now is a floating text block over the image that I have to manually align. Here is an example of one of my figures (I defined a custom float called a Scheme):

```
\begin{Scheme}[h]
  \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{chp_diazobkg/images/shioiritwo}
   \begin{textblock}{1}(1.65,-0.8) \cmp{aax} \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{1}(7,-1) \cmp{aay} \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{1}(13,-1) \cmp{aaz} \end{textblock}
  \begin{textblock}{1}(17.5,-0.5) \cmp{aba} \end{textblock}
  \caption{Facile [1,3]-Brook rearrangement of $\alpha$-keto silane intermediate \ref{cmp:aay}.}
  \label{sch:shioiritwo}
\end{Scheme}
```

Ideally what I would like to be able to do is use a package like pstool/psfrag so that the unique identifiers could be built into the eps file and get replaced with the compound numbers. Using the pstool package, I am able to do text replacements in eps figures, but when I try to do a replacement with a counter psfrag chokes and can't generate the figure. The code below works fine for me so I know the package is installed correctly.

```
\psfragfig[scale=0.8]{test}{
  \psfrag{[aaa]}{testing}
}
```

However, when I try to do something like this no luck (in fact the whole package breaks and no image is generated):

```
\psfragfig[scale=0.8]{test}{
  \psfrag{[aaa]}{\cmp{xxx}}
}
```

Or even something simpler like this just gives ?? for the replaced text:

```
\psfragfig[scale=0.8]{test}{
      \psfrag{[aaa]}{\ref{somefigure}}
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**I have posted a minimal working example with EPS files at:**
https://sites.google.com/site/vrendina/latex

Comment: I guess it's too late now but there are packages like [`chemnum`](http://wwwmctan.org/pkg/chemnum) for this task.

Comment: The approach taken by my own `chemscheme` package is not dissimilar to the one you outline (today I would also recommend `chemnum`, but that's a different issue). Could you provide a small MWE of your input (_i.e_ a complete document), including an EPS somewhere we can get hold of for testing?

Comment: Works for me, even with the same string `[aaa]`. The `??` might mean that the label `somefigure` is not defined. At this point, you really have to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Assuming you're using `\psfragfig` as defined by [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf) then your syntax is wrong. The last argument is _optional_: `\psfragfig[scale=0.8]{scheme}[\psfrag{TMP}{\cmp{xxx}}]`.

Comment: I think I chose not to use chemnum because I didn't want to have to maintain a list of 100+ compounds at the beginning of each chapter. If I moved a scheme from the end of the chapter to the beginning every number would change and I wanted that updated automatically.

Comment: @VictorRendina You only need to pre-define compounds if they pop up 'out of order' in floats. That's true however you choose to do the tracking, as floats and the main text may not exactly line up in the order things appear.

Comment: I just updated the question with a link to a MWE with EPS files. https://sites.google.com/site/vrendina/latex

Comment: I'll add a `\cmpdref+` version to `chemnum` that (like `\cmpd+`) won't create any numbers but fetches them from the `cmpd` file. This should be helpful in floats...

Comment: I may have a hint to what the problem is: it seems that assignments made in the `<replacement>` argument of `\psfrag` are lost in the rest of the document even if they are global like `\refstepcounter`. Similarly the test if the label exists that is done by `\ref` fails as it always finds it undefined. Why this is happening I don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem arose because the [pstool package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstool) creates a separate document containing each figure, and then compiles this with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` to create a new version of the figure with `psfrag` replacements included.

According to section 5.2 of the [pstool package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstool), support for cross referencing within graphics was added in version 1.5, which I think is slightly newer than the question. The following example works on my machine, so I think the solution is to update your `TeX` distribution, if you have not already done so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[process=all]{pstool}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eqn}
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
\psfragfig[scale=0.7]{myfig}{\psfrag{mouse}[][]{\ref{eqn}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The postscript code for `myfig.eps` is as follows:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Title: myfig.eps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 80 50
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%EndComments
/Times-Roman findfont 15 scalefont
setfont
20 20 moveto (mouse) show showpage
%%Trailer
%EOF
```